Is it good practice to modify a session with a GET request?
I am trying to implement an invitation system in Django, compatible with django-allauth. It is similar to django-invitations, but I have some requirements that require a custom implementation.
After researching ways to do it, the only thing I have come up with so far is sending an invite link that, when accessed, adds a flag to the current session to tell django-allauth that signups are open for that session. I think doing something like this is what allauth's docs recommend, although it does not go much into details.
However, I have read in multiple places that a GET request should not cause side effects (here's one of many sources). Since django sessions are by default backed by a database, I think that modifying the session on a GET request (i.e. clicking the invitation link) would mean causing side-effects.
The problem is, I cannot think of another way to do it, except heavily modifying django-allauth's views, which would be a lot more work, and possibly unsafe for an unexperienced developer like me.
So, is it the case that I should not modify the session on a GET request? If so, what other alternatives do I have?

Pedagogy has its place, but you don't have to be a slave to it.  If what you're doing is sensible, then do it.


is it the case that I should not modify the session on a GET request?

No - you can do that.
The justification is this: HTTP constrains the semantics (meaning) of methods, but does not constrain the implementation.  So GET means "please send me a current selected representation for the target resource"; anything else you do while handling that request is on you.
See Fielding, 2002.
An important thing to be aware of is the uniform interface constraint -- general purpose HTTP components are going to assume that sending a GET to your resources means the same thing as sending a GET request targeting any other resource on the web.  Since the meaning of those messages is constrained to be "essentially read-only", they can be sent in a wide array of circumstances (spiders indexing the web, browsers pre-caching links to improve perceived response time, caches refreshing, lost requests being retransmitted, and so on).
So you'll want to think about the possible impact of any side effects you introduce in your handling of GET requests.
